# inefficient query on mongo db

Tags: performance, mongodb, database-design

I have a product which use mongo db partially as storage for notifications. It's live almost for two months and we're facing serious performance issues.
Let me introduce structure that we designed for the notification problem;

There are three basic collections.

`notification_item, notification_subscriptions and notification_actions`

All user created data on the system creates a `notification_item` which includes `owner`, `creation_date` and some other `meta data`

Then owner of the data (which creates at firs step) subscribe on that `notification_item` through `notification_subscription` collection. 
`notification_subscription` consist of `notification_item's object id` (which reference to `notification_item` collection) and `user_id` who subscribed.

Last is `notification_action` collection. It's simple any action on any notification item is inserted. It's structure `notification_item's object id`, `creation_date` and `other meta data`. Any user create an notification action also subscribe for that notification item to listen further notifications.

Anyway so far documents size as count ;

```
notification_items = 4348
```

`notification_subscription = 11324` and

```
notification_action = 12226
```

The problem begins if I want to query on notification_action for a user who subscribed for the most of notification_items query runs so slow.

let's say a user subscribed for number of

```
notification_items = 778
```

It runs for 15 seconds on local to fetch all actions for that user.
Here is the query(it's php but i tested it with javascript which is same result);

```
public function getNewNotificationsByUserId($id){

    $loggingImpl = new LoggingImpl();

    $subsColl = "notification_sub";

    $cursor = $this->mongoDb->db->$subsColl->find(array("user_id" => "$id"));

    $subs = array();

    while($doc = $cursor->getNext()){

        $subs[] = array("not_item._id" => $doc['not_item'],'creation_date' => array('$gte' => $doc['creation_date']));  
    }

    $actions = array();

    if(empty($subs)){
        return $actions;
    }


    $actionColl = NotificationAction::COLL;


    $query = array('$or' => $subs, 'owner.id' => array('$ne' => "$id" ));

    $d1 = microtime(true);
    $cursor = $this->mongoDb->db->$actionColl->find($query)->sort(array('creation_date' => -1));

    while($doc = $cursor->getNext()){

        $actions[] = $doc;
    }
    $d2 = microtime(true);
    $loggingImpl->logDebug("notification data:".($d2-$d1));

    return $actions;
}
```

After index on `creation_date` of `notification_action` performance improved to `0.97` second.

But it's still to bad for a product. Database is not even moderate full. I have concern for future loads. 
What do you suggest? It can be tuned by simple tricks? Or do I need to re design my structure?

edit: here is the query log;

```
> db.system.profile.find().limit(10).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty()
{
    "op" : "query",
    "ns" : "splive.notification_action",
    "query" : {
        "$query" : {
            "$or" : [
                {
                    "not_item._id" : ObjectId("51991be7a46da17941000000"),
                    "creation_date" : {
                        "$gte" : ISODate("2013-08-08T14:05:54.170Z")
                    }
                }, ... (***778 item***)
             ],
            "owner.id" : {
                "$ne" : "1"
            }
        },
        "$orderby" : {
            "creation_date" : -1
        }
    },
    "ntoreturn" : 0,
    "ntoskip" : 0,
    "nscanned" : 12226,
    "keyUpdates" : 0,
    "numYield" : 1,
    "lockStats" : {
        "timeLockedMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(912990),
            "w" : NumberLong(0)
        },
        "timeAcquiringMicros" : {
            "r" : NumberLong(10239),
            "w" : NumberLong(8)
        }
    },
    "nreturned" : 0,
    "responseLength" : 20,
    "millis" : 902,
    "ts" : ISODate("2013-08-08T15:58:39.758Z"),
    "client" : "127.0.0.1",
    "allUsers" : [ ],
    "user" : ""
}
```

Comment: It's a little hard to follow and visualize your schema. What other indexes have you defined? Have you done an explain (from the shell) on any of the queries to see what it's doing?

Comment: you're right it's hard to follow. There is also index on not_item. I added the query log maybe it helps.

Comment: It's scanning every document it appears. I'm not sure if creating a compound index on the `not_item._id` and the `creation_date` would help. Is the creation date variable per `$or`?

Comment: yeap creation date per $or. compound index didn't help.

Comment: Not confident that this will ever scale well as is.

Comment: I guess i should implement another approach to succeed a scalable efficient solution.